# MD5 value for file in a remote FTP server using Python ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, md5, file-transfer, ftplib

Once transferring a file to a server using ftplib, how do I determine the MD5 of that file to the one in my local server?

```
from ftplib import FTP
import hashlib

ftp = FTP('server')
ftp.login('username','password')
ftp.cwd('path_to_upload')

file_to_upload = open(file,'rb') 
filename = os.path.basename(file)
ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + filename, file_to_upload)

local_file_hash = hashlib.md5(open(file, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
# not sure how to achieve this
server_file_hash = hashlib.md5(open(filename, 'rb').read()).hexdigest() 

if local_file_hash == server_file_hash:
     print("Successful transfer")
else:
     print("Failure transfer")
```

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your remote server supports the checksum calculation at all. Many do not. I believe there's even no standard FTP command to calculate a checksum of a remote file. There were many proposals and there are many proprietary solutions.

The latest proposal is:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-bryan-ftpext-hash-02

Some of the commands that can be used to calculate checksum are: `XSHA1`, `XSHA256`, `XSHA512`, `XMD5`, `MD5`, `XCRC` and `HASH`.

You can test that with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/). The WinSCP supports all the previously mentioned commands. Test its [checksum calculation function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_properties#checksum) or the [`checksum` scripting command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_checksum). If they work, [enable logging](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/logging) and check, what command and what syntax WinSCP uses against your server. *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Once you find out, what command does your server support (if any), you can use [`FTP.voidcmd` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.voidcmd):

```
ftp.voidcmd("XSHA1 " + filename)
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a similar issue and came across the following solution, which would work regardless of whether server commands are possible

Source: https://smithje.github.io/python/2013/07/02/md5-over-ftp

In short, one could use the `.retrbinary` and load it into `Hash` object:

```py
import ftplib
import hashlib

def get_ftp_md5(ftp, remote_path):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    ftp.retrbinary(f'RETR {remote_path}', m.update)
    return m.hexdigest()
```

Comment: This way you are downloading a complete file back to the local machine. Then it makes little sense to compare the checksums (let only weak one like MD5), as you can compare complete file contents.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Yes it's downloading the file, but as you stated, not all FTPS server allow for HASH commands, so this is a workaround for the same approach.