# How to compute MD5 hash for a file on the remote server using paramiko

Tags: python, ftp, sftp, pysftp

I have achieved how to download a file using SFTP and generate an MD5 hash of the downloaded file locally.

I am trying to upload a file to an SFTP Server and generate its MD5 hash when it's on the server and then download the file and its MD5 hash from the remote server.

How can I computer the MD5 hash on the remote SFTP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very few FTP/SFTP servers support calculation of remote file checksum.

You can try first (my) WinSCP GUI SFTP/FTP client to see if your FTP/SFTP server does. WinSCP supports many standard and non-standard APIs for checksum calculation. So if your server does support such API, WinSCP should be able to make use of it.

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_properties#checksum

---

You wrote about FTP. I've covered that already in:

- [MD5 value for file in a remote FTP server using Python ftplib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62081849/850848)

---

Though you possibly mistake SFTP and FTP. As Paramiko is an SSH/SFTP client. FTP and SFTP and two completely different protocols.

For SFTP/Paramiko, see:

- [How to check if Paramiko successfully uploaded a file to an SFTP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28967969/850848#28980305)
- [What SFTP server implementations support check-file extension](https://serverfault.com/q/853362/168875)

---

If your FTP/SFTP server does not have remote file check sum calculation API, you cannot use FTP/SFTP for this. But commonly, if you have SFTP access (but not so with FTP), you also might have shell access. So you can use shell commands for the checksum calculation.

See [Comparing MD5 of downloaded files against files on an SFTP server in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62475321/850848)